# How many months required for Bank statement of Savings amount to prove origin

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

If the savings balance has been accumulated for a period more than a year. Bank statement required for application of the visit visa is 6 months, and amount saved during the 6 months period is more than enough for the visit, I believe for the the origin of funds saved during the 6 months should be proved. What about the remaining balance that was accumulated more than a year . Do you have to also prove the source of this or the 6 months is enough. If the source is from the same income stream.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Answer (score 1):

The *Maintenance and accommodation* section of the Visit Guidance for caseworkers published by the UK Home Office states:

> Where an individual provides documents which show sufficient funds for their planned stay, but either all or the majority of these funds have not been held in their account for long, you may want to make further checks to establish the origin of this money.

Source: https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1112745/Visit_caseworker_guidance_12.pdf

As explained in this answer [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) six months’ worth of statements is typically enough to satisfy the requirement.

If you’ve been saving regularly over that period, and the funds accumulated from those savings are sufficient to cover the costs of your trip, providing older statements is not necessary. However, there is nothing in the rules to prevent you submitting additional statements, although as stated in https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk you should not provide bank statements or letters issued more than 1 year before the date of your application.